# Adding one Random Real

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I'm studying Kanamori's book The Higher Infinite and now I'm stuck.
I want to prove that forcing with Borel sets of positive measure adds one random real.

Let me state the theorem:

Let $M$ be a countable transitive model for ZFC.

$\mathcal{B} = \{A \in Bor(\omega^\omega): \mu(A) > 0\}$ and $p \leq q \leftrightarrow p \subset q.$

Let $G$ be $\mathcal{B}^{M}$-generic over $M$. Then there is a unique $x \in \omega^\omega$ such that for any closed Borel code $c \in M$,

$$x \in A_{c}^{M[G]} \leftrightarrow A_{c}^{M} \in G$$

and $M[x] = M[G]$.

The proof first asserts:

"(*)For any $n \in \omega$,

$$\{C \in \mathcal{B}^{M}: C\text{ is closed }\land \exists k (C \subset \{f \in \omega^\omega: f(n) = k\})\},$$

is dense in $\mathcal{B}^M$."

My first question: Why? Is it obvious? I think I need at least a hint!

[...]Some irrelevant comments.

"Arguing in $M[G]$: there is a unique $x \in \omega^\omega$ specified by

$$\{x\} = \bigcap \{A_{c}^{M[G]}: c \in M \text{ is a closed code }\land A_{c}^{M} \in G\}$$

since this is an intersection of closed sets with the finite intersection property and (*) holds"

Can someone explain it to me more detailed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Let $A_k=\{f\in\omega^\omega: f(n)=k\}$. Fix $C\in \mathcal B^M,$ note that  $\bigcup_{k\in\omega}A_k=\omega^\omega$ thus $C=C\cap (\bigcup_{k\in\omega}A_k)=\bigcup_{k\in\omega}(C\cap A_k)$. It follows that there is a $k$ so that $C\cap A_k$ has positive measure. Hence $C\cap A_k\leq C$ and satisfies $(*)$.